# Ambari server is not running on port 8080 on Mac M1

Tags: sandbox, ambari

I have install docker desktop, increase its memory to 10GB and the pull the HDP sandbox
Then i set the environment variable is the host file, after that when I am trying to launch dashboard it saying Bad Gateway because Ambari server is not running 8080, I have checked that port nothing is running on that port and still Ambari is not running on it

I have attached Picture below to show the error and random port on Ambari server starts running

[image]

[image]